# Bash history with duration of each command

Tags: linux, bash

**Is there any trick to display *history* of commands with the duration of those commands. I would like to know how much it took to end the command and return to the shell.**

I don't want to use *time* explicitly prefixing each command - I would like to embed the information to the ones I have below.

*I know how to get the history output with timestamps and dates by doing so, but I would also like to know how much actual time it took until the command exited*

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
history
```

*I get the following output*

```
...
1843  2023-03-01 13:17:20 export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
1844  2023-03-01 13:17:22 history
```

Comment: You could use a trap on DEBUG to store the timestamp of the start time, and then use a PROMPT_COMMAND to store the duration of the command in the history file.

Answer (score 3):

For simple functionality, you could append the duration to the history file with something like:

```
$ store_start() { start_time=$(date +%s.%N); }                                                                                                                                                                                          
$ trap store_start DEBUG                                                                                                                                                                                                                
$ record_duration() { history -a; { printf "$start_time "; date +%s.%N; } | awk '{print "#", $2 - $1; }' >> $HISTFILE; }                                                                                                                    
$ PROMPT_COMMAND=record_duration
```

The DEBUG trap is executed before each command, storing the start time in `$start_time`.  The PROMPT_COMMAND executes after your command finishes, writing out the last command to the $HISTFILE with `history -a` and then appending the duration of the command.  This is extremely fragile; the interaction of debug traps and PROMPT_COMMAND is fickle; use at your own risk.  For example, if you have multiple shells all with the same HISTFILE, it will be hard to determine which duration goes with which command.  If you add the pid of the shell to HISTFILE and keep the history of shells separate, merging the histories as needed, simply appending duration can be made to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can get that information, but you can always use `time command` to get an estimate of how long the previous command lasted.

you can also run `time !history_command_number` if you don't like to repeat the command again.

but for sure this won't be accurate for commands you have used to process files, copy files, etc.